# Any way to pause rendering or bundle UI operations in a transaction on Android?

Tags: android

So I have an animation active on a View, and when the rendering is done I want to permanently move the View to the new coordinates. I do this the following way

```
mTargetView.setAnimation(null);
mTargetView.setX(newX);
mTargetView.setY(newY);
mTargetView.setRotation(0F);
```

The problem is that I see the view flicker between the animation resetting and the translation/rotation is executed. How can I avoid that? Any way to say to the UI engine "don't draw anything until further notice?" so that I can bundle my changes in a transaction?

PS: Yes, I know I may set `setFillAfter(true)` on the animation to make the View stick, but the end result is not the same.

Comment: please dont mix pre v4 stuff (startAnimation) and post v4 stuff (setX/Y/Rotation), do it either -v4 or v4+ way

Comment: Please elaborate. I did not know startAnimation was pre-v4. It is not deprecated. What shall I use instead to start/stop an animation? I am both manually (setX) and automatically animating (Animation-classes), so I cannot "use either". I am not doing this simultaneously though, hence the setAnimation(null)

Comment: Use ObjectAnimator and the PropertyAnimation framework. With this framework, the objects get animated, not only the bitmap representations.

Comment: yes, like  ElDuderino said, instead of **Animations** you should use **Animators**, see: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html, you should use Property Animation

Comment: Thanks I solved my problem by rewriting to using Animators. Classic case of "asking the wrong question" I guess :)